# Python: Remove line if string appears in column

Tags: python, pandas, filtering

I am loading an excel spreadsheet (n lines x 33 columns) using

```
inputfile = pd.read_excel()
```

and would like to apply a filter.
My goal is to have a list of strings such as the one below

```
Filter = ["Material_1", "Material_2"]
```

and keep the lines in the `inputfile`, which either contains Material_1 or Material_2 (potentially later more options) in column 13 of the `inputfile`.

Many thanks.

Comment: So you want to keep only the rows of your inputfile that in column 13 they have either 'Material_1' or 'Material_2' ? What is the actual name of column 13?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The column's name is Materials. I used the code from Sam, without the tilde. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subset the dataframe and use is in like so:

```
Filter = ["Material_1", "Material_2"]
df = df[df["<column_name>"].isin(Filter)]
```

This will give you the only the rows where that specific column is in your filter list.

Comment: Super, many thanks. It actually does what I want when I use your lines without the tilde.

Comment: Apologies I misread and thought you wanted to remove these rows rather than keep just these rows! I have edited.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sam, you anyway solved my problem perfectly.